# Импорт в коде, который выполняется много раз

Tags: python

Разбирая чужой код, наткнулся на подобный фрагмент:

```
@property
def foo(self):
    from some_module import something
    return something['some_param']
```

Насколько хорошим решением является использование импорта в коде, который должен исполняться многократно и быстро? (а ведь тяжёлые функции не рекомендуется оформлять как propety).

Будет ли импорт каждый раз выполняться при вызове этого свойства или интерпретатор в таких случаях выполняет импорт только один раз?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хотя интерпретатор кэширует модуль после 1 импорта, 2 импорт все равно не будет выполняется быстро. Поэтому, а также для увеличение понятности кода рекомендуют весь импорт помещать наверх а не в функции. Поэтому код:

```
@property
def foo(self):
    from some_module import something
    return something['some_param']
```

неправильный. `from some_module import something` надо поднять наверх. Хотя стоит заметить что в отдельных случаях (решение проблем импорта например) такой код может быть "оправдан".

P.S: Замер скорости импорта.

Код:

```
from timeit import timeit

def slow():
    for i in range(1000):
        import os

def fast():
    import os
    for i in range(1000):
        pass

def stub():
    for i in range(1000):
        pass
```

Замеры:

```
timeit("slow()", "from __main__ import slow, fast, stub", number=1000)
```

> 3.3150182569997924

```
timeit("fast()", "from __main__ import slow, fast, stub", number=1000)
```

> 0.15638045699961367

```
timeit("stub()", "from __main__ import slow, fast, stub", number=1000)
```

> 0.15032413299923064

Comment: «2 импорт все равно не будет выполняеться быстро» — а можно объяснение почему?

Comment: @andreymal любая операция импорта состоит из 4 частей: выполнение байткода(питон медленный, поэтому даже просто проход по коду дело не быстрое), поиск подуля, компиляция, исполнение кода модуля. При 1 импорте происходит все четире операции, при 2 первые две.

Comment: Сообственно можно на замерах увидеть сколько занимат 1 и 2 операция. 1 операция занимает `0.15032413299923064` а вторая `0.006`(то есть  2 операция занимет немного). Но если везде писать такой код, то замедление будет видно.

Comment: Спасибо, я в целом так и думал. Просто увидел вот этот вот кусок в коде, который вроде как серьёзные люди писали, и засомневался - вдруг я просто не очень хорошо понимаю механику импортов.

Comment: @andreymal второй и последующие импорты, по сути равнозначны: `something = getattr(sys.modules['some_module'], 'something', sys.modules.get('some_module.something'))`. Обычно, на уровне функции импорты не используют вовсе не из-за производительности, а чтобы было ясно, какие другие модули текущий модуль использует (чтобы по сути глобальные объекты не прятать внутри функций). Всегда, когда импорт внутри функции, должна быть явная причина, по которой его туда поместили: к примеру, чтобы цикл разорвать импортов.